# Creating "Other" response to Google form response through Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Apps script that's attempting to populate a form response and provide "Other" choices as a response. The questions allow other responses (showOtherOption is set to true) and I'm attempting to do this with both MultipleChoiceItem and CheckBoxItem question types.

My current implementation (below) creates the response but when you look at the individual responses through the Google Form UI the "Other" option is not selected and the additional option is not displayed.

```
var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
var mcItem = form.getItems()[indexOfMCItem].asMultipleChoiceItem();
formResponse.withItemResponse(mc.createResponse(["Real Option", "My Other Option"]));
```

In the example above, the response is created and displayed in the UI:

- The Summary display in Google Forms correctly display the "My Other Option" as being an "Other" response [Expected]
- If the responses are exported, the "My Other Option" is listed as a response [Expected]
- If I browse the individual responses through the UI, the "Other" option is not selected and the "My Other Option" is not displayed anywhere [Not Expected]

Is there a way to create an "Other" response for a MutipleChoiceItem or CheckBoxItem that correctly displays the individual responses?

Comment: Try to enable the [showOtherOption(true)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#showotheroptionenabled) because the default value for [CheckboxItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item) and MultipleChoiceItem is false. This maybe the reason they're not showing.

Comment: The `showOtherOption` is set to true and if you provide an "Other" answer through the Google Forms UI it shows up correctly in the individual results.